# Python Code won't run when including function

Tags: python

I'm experimenting with lists and inputs (I'm quite new) and I've come across this problem with my code:
If I comment out the function the input code works fine. I don't know whats wrong.

I've tried moving around the code and re-writing it in different ways, but that didn't work.

```py
students = []
forms = []


def main(formCount, allform):
    while len(students) < formCount:
        studentName = input("Student's Name:")
        students.append(studentName)
        forms.append(allform)
        print("Student Added:" studentName "in" allform)
        print("-------------")

for s,f in zip(students, forms):
    print(s, f)

formNo = input("Number of Students:")
form = input("Student Form:")
main(formNo, form)
```

Expected Result:
It would ask for the number of students in the form, then the form, and then it would move on to getting the students' names.

Actual Result:
Nothing shows up in the terminal (I'm using the external terminal in Visual Studio Code).

I don't get any error messages, but when I try to continue it says invalid syntax.

Comment: What do expect to get in `Student Form` from the user?

Comment: It's to get the class that the students are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this part:

```py
for s,f in zip(students, forms):
    print(s, f)
```

To be the last part of the code - after the `main(formNo, form)` - this way the code will print out all the values, accumulated in `main` function.

In addition, in order for the code to run properly add `int` "casting" to this line:

```
while len(students) < int(formCount):
```

Since the `formCount` you get from user input is `string` and you can't compare between `int` and `string`.

One more thing, the print statement is formatted not correctly, if you are using Python 3.6+ you can just use the `f-string` functionality:

```py
print(f"Student Added: {studentName} in {allform}")
```

The ouput of your script should be something like this:

```py
Number of Students:2
Student Form:Test
Student's Name:Tim
Student Added: Tim in Test
-------------
Student's Name:Tom
Student Added: Tom in Test
-------------
Tim Test
Tom Test
```

Comment: @ANameThatIChose, pay attention for my edit, regarding the `int` "casting"

Comment: Nope, nothing appears.

Comment: @ANameThatIChose, any errors? Are you prompted to enter the input?

Comment: No, the terminal just appears.

Comment: @ANameThatIChose, do you run the file which has this script in? How do you do it?

Comment: If I try to run it directly from the file, the terminal opens and then closes immediately. If I try to run it from the debugger the terminal is blank.

Comment: @ANameThatIChose, ok. Run a test snippet, like this:
`students = ['Tim', 'Tom']
print(students)
`
Do you see the output of the print function?

Comment: As in replacing students = []? If so, that doesn't work either. Terminal is blank.

Comment: No, just these two lines. To make sure that you see the print result.

Comment: That's strange. I am running the same code, with the 3 fixes I've suggested to you and it produces the output I've pinned to the end of the answer.

Comment: Oh, I think you're f-string suggestion made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Great, so you had some error before, make sure to pay attention to everything outputted to the console. If my answer helped - you can upvote it!